# Does Keycloak supports Java 21?

Tags: java, keycloak

I would like to know if Keycloak supports Java 21 and from which version of Keycloak. If not, when it will be.

I have tested Keycloak 21.1.1 on Java Amazon Corretto 21 and have not find any problem so far. Unfortunatelly I have not found any clue in documentation.

Comment: https://www.keycloak.org/getting-started/getting-started-zip

Comment: So you tested Keycloak 21.1.1 with Java 21, if everything is functional and you have no errors, what exactly is your question.

Comment: @Ramhound I have tested basic functionality but do not know if there are some hidden bugs or known issues. The documentation does not mention Java 21 anywhere.

Comment: Java is backwards compatible with itself

Comment: This is a question only the dev can answer, and we are not the dev. If they have published this info, that will be available to you as much as it will be to us.